# How to minimize JInternalFrame using [Esc] key in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I used `InputMap` and `ActionMap` to binding Esc to closing window, by using `setVisible(false)`. How can I create [Esc] Hotkey to minimize the window in java swing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using

```
frame.setVisible( false );
```

You would use:

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
```

You should also check out [Dialog Escape Key](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/escape-key-and-dialog/) for a more complete implementation that will handle the Escape key. For example the code will allow closing of popup windows (on a combo box) to close before attempting to close the dialog. The code was written for a dialog and would need to be modified slightly for a JFrame.

Comment: Correct. Your question was how to minimize a window, which I assume you meant to be a JFrame.  When you minimize a frame, the icon appears on your task bar. You can't minimize a panel. At least I have no idea what that concept means to you.

Comment: I see you changed your question and you are now talking about a `JInternalFrame`. Well, read the `JInternalFrame` API. You will find a method that allows you to set the maximum/minimum state of the internal frame.